# Flutter future Boolean function always return default value

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder, flutter-future, flutter-functional-widget

I have a Future boolean function in that function I checked some data using the map function. if and else both conditions set the boolean variable is true. but it always returns the default false value. below code is my function.

```
  Future<bool> checkisShowablebydepend(Questions questions) async {
    bool isDependvalue = false;

    questions.dependFields.map((e) async {
      bool isequal = (questions.dependValue.toLowerCase() ==
          _formKey.currentState.fields[e].value.toLowerCase());

      if (isequal) {
        isDependvalue = true;
      } else {
        isDependvalue = true;
      }
    });

    return isDependvalue;
  }
```

here this is how i got data from above function.

```
  Widget loadWidgets(Questions questions) {
    if (questions.depend) {
      return FutureBuilder<bool>(
          future: checkisShowablebydepend(questions),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.none:
                return new Text('Press button to start');
              case ConnectionState.waiting:
                return new Text('Awaiting result...');
              default:
                if (snapshot.hasError)
                  return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                else
                  return new Text('Result: ${snapshot.data}');
            }
          });
    } else {
      return selectFormfield(questions);
    }
  }
```

Comment: that's because return is called before .map function ends  try printing the isDependvalue inside .map function

Comment: @MohamedInshaf - I tried print inside map function but that's not showing

Comment: then check data is passing through the "questions" list, try printing it outside the map function

Comment: and also you have to use  await to get the future data

Comment: I used FutureBuilder for get this data, i added that code also please check.

Answer (score 1):

> **`Async`** means that this function is asynchronous and you might need to
> wait a bit to get its result.
>
> **`Await`** means - wait here until this function is finished and you will
> get its return value.

The await keyword only works within an async function.

You have set the function as `sync` so you can use `await` keyword to wait for the comparison result

```
questions.dependFields.map((e) async {
      bool isequal = await (questions.dependValue.toLowerCase() ==
          _formKey.currentState.fields[e].value.toLowerCase());

      if (isequal) {
        isDependvalue = true;
      } else {
        isDependvalue = true;
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to iterate trough your `questions.dependFields` list, then [forEach](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/forEach.html) seems more appropriate.

I'm not sure that this functions needs to be `Future` by the way.